# If there's no Goel Hadam (ex: victim was a convert), does the accidental killer still need to go to an Ir Miklat?

Tags: talmud-gemara, city-of-refuge, maseches-makos

Suppose Reuvein was accidentally killed by Shimon. It turns out that Reuvein is a *ger* who has no *halachik* relatives.

Since Reuvein has no next-of-kin  and thus no one who can kill Shimon- does Shimon still need to go to an *Ir Miklat*, and if so, why?

Comment: Makkos 2b says it's a kapara for the killer. I would assume he should try to get one even if his physical life isn't in danger

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @mbloch, I read the perush of Rav Pearl on Sefer Hamitsvot from Rasag. **This is a Machloket Rishonim**.

> וכתב בחי' הר"ן ז"ל שם שחובת גואל הדם היא שהוא יטעון טענותיו בפני ב"ד על שראוי להמיתו ושאם אין לו גואל הדם שב"ד מעמידין אדם אחר תחת גואל הדם שיטעון בחובת הרוצח. וכדאמרינן בפרק אחד ד"מ (ל"ג ע"ב) חובתי' דמאן חובתי' דגואל הדם. אלמא הוא טוען כל טענות שיוכל לטעון נגד הרוצח. וג"כ כששפטו ב"ד את הרוצח למות מצוה ביד גוה"ד להמיתו שישפוך עליו חמתו. **ואם אין שם גואל הדם מצוה ביד אחר להמיתו** עכ"ל עיי"ש. וא"כ **עבד כנעני שאין לו גואל הדם שישגיח עליו**. בכל כיו"ב שהעבד תחת אדונים קשים שרגילים להכותו מכה רבה. שאין גואל הדם אלא כל הראוי לירושה. כמש"כ הרמב"ם ז"ל (ריש הלכות רוצח ה"ב) עיי"ש. והרי עבד כנעני אין לו יורשים. דאין לו חייס לא למעלה ולא למטה. כמבואר ביבמות (פרק הבע"י ס"ב ע"א). ובב"ב (פרק מי שמת קמ"ט ע"א) בתוס' (ד"ה כל דאיתי') כתבו בפשיטות דעבד ליתי' בירושה עיי"ש. וכן מתבאר בגיטין (פרק השולח מ"ג ע"א) ובתוס' שם (ד"ה ואי אמרת) עייש"ה. וכ"כ הרב המאירי ז"ל (ריש פרק בתרא דנזיר ס"ב ע"ב) עיי"ש בדבריו. ודברי רש"י ותוס' שם (ד"ה א"ה עבדים) שלא כתבו שם כן עיי"ש. תמוהים מאוד. וכבר עמדו קצת אחרונים ז"ל על דבריהם ואכמ"ל בזה. **וכיון דאין גואל לעבד כנעני. נמצא שחובת הצבור והב"ד היא להעמיד לו גואל שיטפל בו בזה:** ‏

Relevant points: A slave, who has no relationship, no upward and no downward, has no natural Goel Hadam, **Rambam, Ran and Meiri** wrote that the Bet Din officially appoints a Goel Hadam.

Answer (score 4):

There is a relevant gemara in [Sanhedrin 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.45b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that, if there is no blood redeemer (*goel*), the court appoints one

> As it is taught in a baraita: The verse states: “The blood redeemer
>   shall slay the murderer when he meets him” (Numbers 35:21). This
>   mitzva of redeeming the death caused by an unintentional killer falls
>   on the blood redeemer, a relative of the victim. **And from where is it
>   derived that if the victim has no blood redeemer the court appoints a
>   blood redeemer for him? As it is stated: “When he meets him,” which
>   teaches that in any case he shall slay the murderer, whether he is a
>   relative or a court-appointed blood redeemer.**

In this scenario, the murderer better get to a city of refuge fast!

The Artscroll commentary notes multiple interpretations of the above *baraita*. Rashi understands it as referring to a killer who went to a city of refugee but left it. Others (incl. Ran) note the halacha follows the view that only a relative of the deceased may attack a killer who leaves a city of refuge (following the dispute in [Makot 12a](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.12a.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). There as well R Yosei HaGelili is of the opinion that anyone can kill the murderer if there is no redeemer.